# AS3 - Recycling objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is this the correct, most efficient way to recycle objects when creating an array of objects?

```
package com {
    public class CreateList extends MovieClip {
        //this is the object I will be recycling
        private var newProperty:PropertyRow;

        //this is the array I will use to reference the objects
        private var _theRows:Array = new Array();

        public function CreateList() {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
                //null the object
                newProperty = null;

                //create a new instance of the object
                newProperty = new PropertyRow();

                //store a reference to the object before nulling it in the next for loop cycle.
                _theRows.push(newProperty);
            }

            //null the last object that was created in the for loop
            newProperty = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `new` keyword will instantiate a new instance of PropertyRow. The GC won't free up memory after setting the variable to `null`, because the instances are still retained in the array. Therefore, using a member variable will not bring any performance advantage over using a temp variable within your creation loop.

If you're going to optimize your code for performance, you should first try to always use Vectors instead of Arrays.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

As I've found out while testing vector performance for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays/8551727#8551727), this is true only for number types!  If you are going to use a vector of any object type, Array will in fact be faster!  The rest of my answer below still applies, though - just use Arrays instead of `Vector.<PropertyRow>`.

**END EDIT**

Then, if it's avoidable, don't use push(), but bracket syntax (only if you know the exact size of the vector - this is important, otherwise the bracket syntax won't work):

```
var vec_size:int = 1000;
var myArray:Array = new Array (vec_size); 
for (var i : int = 0; i< vec_size; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new PropertyRow(); // if you're not setting any properties, you won't even need a temp variable ;)
}
```

If you are worried about garbage collection and reusing objects, also check out Adobe's reference on [object pooling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-19cd3c2412513c24bce-8000.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need to create field for this temp object.

```
package com {
    public class CreateList extends MovieClip {
        //this is the array I will use to reference the objects
        private var _theRows:Array = new Array();

        public function CreateList() {
            var newProperty:PropertyRow;
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
                //create a new instance of the object
                newProperty = new PropertyRow();
                //store a reference to the object before nulling it in the next for loop cycle.
                _theRows.push(newProperty); 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

in this case newProperty will be a local variable that will destroyed automatically then function ends. You don`t need to null it anywhere.