# Is there any advantage in using Vector.<Object> in place of a standard Array?

Tags: actionscript-3, data-structures

Because of the inability to create Vectors dynamically, I'm forced to create one with a very primitive type, i.e. Object:

```
var list:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
```

I'm assuming that Vector gains its power from being typed as closely as possible, rather than the above, but I may be wrong and there are in-fact still gains when using the above in place of a normal Array or Object:

```
var list:Array = [];
var list:Object = {};
```

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Strick typing is always faster. Some good reading http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/2010/08/as3-array-vs-vector/

Comment: @The_asMan - Not true for reference types in Actionscript

Comment: yes it is because there is less overhead iterating through the vector because of the type casting.

Comment: Not sure if `for each(i:T in Vector|Array)` already eliminates those problems anyway.

Comment: You have the ability to create vectors dynamically: new (getDefinitionByName("\_\_AS3\_\_.vec::Vector.<flash.display::Sprite>"))()

Comment: @Pavelfljōt I ain't putting that hideous thing into my framework.

Comment: @Pavel, wow that's clever! Ugly, but clever.

Comment: that's totally ok. Just have a utility (static) class with a method like createVector(type:Class):Object

Comment: Yeah - just appears really hacky, reason being that a lot of Vector's benefits are at compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not gain any benefits from Vector.< Object > compared to Array or vice versa. Also the underlying data structure will be the same even if you have a tighter coupled Vector such as Vector.< Foo >. The only optimization gains will be if you use value types. The reason for this is that Ecmascript will still be late binding and all reference objects share the same referencing byte structure.

However, in Ecmascript 4 (of which Actionscript is an implementation) the Vector generic datatype adds bounds checking to element access (the non-vector will simply grow the array), so the functionality varies slightly and consequently the number of CPU clock cycles will vary a little bit. This is negligible however.

Comment: Joachim, this is very incorrect. There are many benchmarks online that prove otherwise with both generic and typed Vectors.

Comment: @JonathanDunlap No, it's you who are wrong.  Vectors only bring performance improvements when used with numerical types: int, uint and Number. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays/8551727#8551727

Comment: @weltraumpirat, mind blowing info here. At least, primitive types get the improvement. heh

Comment: @Joachim, with this new info I wish I could remove my downvote on your reply. However, you will have to edit your post first before I can be able to.

Comment: @JonathanDunlap. To clarify why this is: The value types (int,float) can be optimized into a single memory allocation whereas a reference type cannot. The cost of a referenced objects remain the same regardless of type, i.e. the reference itself and the object allocated in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage I've seen is that coding is a bit easier with vectors, because FlashDevelop (and most coding tools for as3) can do code hinting better. so I can do `myVector.` and see my methods and functions, array won't let you do that without casting `myArr[2] as myObject` (thought this kind of casting is rumoured to make it faster, not slower)

Array's sort functions are faster however, but if it is speed you're after, you might be better served by linked lists (pending the application)

I think using vectors is the proper way to be coding, but not necessarily better.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question- Vectors have a tremendous value! Vector. vs Array is a bad example of the differences though and benchmarks may be similar. However, Vector. vs Array is DEFINITELY better both memory and processing. The speed improvement comes from Flash not needing to "box" and "unbox" the values (multiple mathematical operations required for this). Also, Array cannot allocate memory as effectively as a typed Vector. Strict-typing collections are almost always better.

Benchmarks:
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/636
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/09/24/actioscript-3-vector-array-performance-comparison/

Even .NET suffers from boxing collections (Array):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173196.aspx

**UPDATE**:

```
I've been corrected! Only primitive numeric types get a performance enhancement 
from Vectors. You won't see any improvement with Array vs Vector.<Object>.
```

Comment: I won't down vote you, because I've been misled in much the same way you have, but you *are* wrong.  Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays/8551727#8551727

Comment: Hmm... I need to run benchmarks on this. In theory, at least all the primitive types should be faster with Vector's. This is very sad if complex types get no benefits from Vectors. :/