# Optimising AS3 draw speed of line waves. Ready to run files and performance analyser included

Tags: actionscript-3

I have attached a zip with an FLA that you can run in CS 5.5. The animation contains a performance analyser and sliders to control various parameters.

Demo:
http://sephardi.ehclients.com/alivetest/index.html
Click anywhere to start the animation

Files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rcpvzo1h7br8fh/alivesource.zip

I have written a program that draws lines pixel by pixel and animates them in a wave-like manner, and displaces certain pixels using a displacement map.

This is what happens on each loop:

1. Display objects and variables from previous loop are cleared
2. Displacement map is stored in a bitmap data object
3. A line is drawn pixel by pixel by reading the y coordinates stored in an array. It's value is also altered using corresponding displacement map and sine wave data.

I have setup sliders with which you can control how many lines are drawn (linecount), the width of each line (canvaswidth), and the resolution of each line (res).

The performance is pretty poor, and I would like your help in optimising it. Maybe there is nothing I can do to optimise my code, please let me know.

I don't think caching as bitmap data is possible because the lines are in permanent motion

Keep in mind, I would really like to preserve 35 lines and a resolution of 1 pixel per iteration

Many thanks

UPDATE:
I am now using drawPath to draw the line rather than drawing pixel by pixel.

```
/*
Click anywhere on the stage to start anim
*/


import flash.display.BitmapData;
import com.greensock.*;
import flash.display.Shape;
import uk.co.soulwire.*;
import net.hires.debug.Stats;
import uk.co.soulwire.gui.SimpleGUI;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;


/*
Performance analyser and variable sliders
*/
var stats:Stats;
var gui:SimpleGUI;
var guiholder:MovieClip;
stats=new Stats();
stats.x = 1200;
stats.y = 0;
addChild(stats);
gui = new SimpleGUI(this,"Parameters","h",1000,0);
gui.show();

/*
Stores the base coordinates
*/
var c:Coordinates;
c=new Coordinates();

/*
Holds the lines
*/
var holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip  ;
addChild(holder);


/*
Generic variables
*/
var i:uint;
var j:uint;
var line:Sprite;
var lines:Array = [];
var bmd:BitmapData;
var brightness = 0;
var sinus = 0;






/**
*
Parameters used to control the animaitons and extrusions
*
**/


/*
How many pixels do we draw in each loop?
*/
var scaleFactor:Number=2
var canvasWidth:Number = 999;
var lineCount:Number = 35;
var res = 1;//Skip res-1 pixels per loop to lower the resolution

/*
Displacement map properties
*/
var extrusion:Number = 1;
var extrusiontarget:Number = .1;
var tolerance:Number = 1;
var smoothness = 10;

//Sinewave 
var lasti = 0;
var sinedirection = -1;
var sineamplitude:Number = 3;
var sinespeed = 0.5;
var sinedensity = 100;

/*
Breathing animation
*/
var inhale:Number = 2;
var exhale:Number = 2;
var beforeInhale:Number = 0;
var beforeExhale:Number = 0;

/*
Add sliders to control the above variables
*/
gui.addGroup("Pixels being drawn");
gui.addSlider("lineCount", 5, 35);
gui.addSlider("canvasWidth",30,999);
gui.addSlider("res",1,10);

gui.addGroup("Displacement Map");
gui.addSlider("smoothness", 1, 100,{callback:setBlur});
gui.addSlider("tolerance", 1, 255);
gui.addSlider("extrusiontarget", 0.1, 3);

gui.addGroup("Sinwave");
gui.addSlider("sinedirection",-1,1);
gui.addSlider("sineamplitude",0,30);
gui.addSlider("sinespeed",0,10);

gui.addGroup("Breathing");
gui.addSlider("beforeInhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("inhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("beforeExhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("exhale",0,5);




/**
Loop
**/
function myEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    /*
    Start a new iteration of line drawing, triggered when you click anywhere ons tage
    */
    drawLines();
}





function drawLines():void {


    for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        holder.removeChild(lines[i]);
        lines[i] = null;
    }
    lines = [];
    for (i=0; i<lineCount; i++) {
        drawLine(i);
    }

}


function resetBitmapData(){
    bmd = null;
    bmd = new BitmapData(canvasWidth,1000);
    bmd.draw(mc);
    mc.visible = false;
}


/**
plot the cordinates of each point absed on sin data and bmp brihgtness
**/


var targety:Number;
var myPath:GraphicsPath;
var myStroke:GraphicsStroke;
var myDrawing:Vector.<IGraphicsData > ;
var myFill:GraphicsSolidFill;
myFill= new GraphicsSolidFill();
myFill.color = 0x000000;

function drawLine(linenumber):void {
    line=new Sprite();
    holder.addChild(line);
    myPath= new GraphicsPath(new Vector.<int>(), new Vector.<Number>());
    myStroke = new GraphicsStroke(res);
    myStroke.fill = new GraphicsSolidFill(0xff0000);// solid stroke
    for (j=0; j<canvasWidth; j+=res) {
        brightness = Math.ceil(getbrightness(getcolor(j,c.coords[linenumber][j]))/tolerance) ;
        sinus= Math.sin((j + (lasti * sinespeed)) / sinedensity) * sineamplitude;
        targety=c.coords[linenumber][j]-(sinus*0)-(brightness*extrusion)-(sinus*(linenumber-15)*1);
        myPath.commands.push(2);
        myPath.data.push(j,targety);
    }
    myPath.commands.push(2);
    myPath.data.push(0,1000);
    myDrawing = new Vector.<IGraphicsData>();
    myDrawing.push(myStroke,myFill, myPath);
    line.graphics.drawGraphicsData(myDrawing);
    lines.push(line);
    lasti -=  sinedirection;
}


/*
Functions to retrieve brightness of displacement map
*/

function getcolor(xx,targety):uint {
    var pixelValue:uint = bmd.getPixel(xx,targety);
    return pixelValue;
}


function getbrightness(colour):Number {
    var R:Number = 0;
    var G:Number = 0;
    var B:Number = 0;
    R +=  colour >> 16 & 0xFF;
    G +=  colour >> 8 & 0xFF;
    B +=  colour & 0xFF;
    var br = Math.sqrt(R * R * .241 + G * G * .691 + B * B * .068);
    return br;
}

/*
Makes the displacment map "breathe"
*/

function grow():void {
    TweenLite.to(this,inhale,{extrusion:extrusiontarget,onComplete:shrink,delay:beforeInhale});
}

function shrink():void {
    TweenLite.to(this,exhale,{extrusion:0,onComplete:grow,delay:beforeExhale});
}




/*
Smoothness of displacement map
*/
var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();

function setBlur():void {
    trace("sb");
    blur.blurX = smoothness;
    blur.blurY = smoothness;
    blur.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
    mc.word.filters = [blur];
    //reset the bitmap data
    resetBitmapData()
}

function mouseDownHandler(e) {
    grow();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myEnterFrame);
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

//Draws lines;
setBlur();
drawLines();
```

OLD CODE:

```
/*
Click anywhere on the stage to start anim
*/


import flash.display.BitmapData;
import com.greensock.*;
import flash.display.Shape;
import uk.co.soulwire.*;
import net.hires.debug.Stats;
import uk.co.soulwire.gui.SimpleGUI;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


/*
Performance analyser and variable sliders
*/
var stats:Stats;
var gui:SimpleGUI;
var guiholder:MovieClip;
stats=new Stats();
stats.x = 1200
stats.y = 0;
addChild(stats);
gui = new SimpleGUI(this,"Parameters","h",1000,0);
gui.show();

/*
Stores the base coordinates
*/
var c:Coordinates;
c=new Coordinates();

/*
Holds the lines
*/
var holder:MovieClip=new MovieClip
addChild(holder)


/*
Generic variables
*/
var i:uint;
var j:uint;
var line:Shape;
var lines:Array = [];
var bmd:BitmapData;
var brightness = 0;
var sinus=0;






/**
*
Parameters used to control the animaitons and extrusions
*
**/


/*
How many pixels do we draw in each loop?
*/
var canvaswidth:Number = 999;
var linecount:Number=35
var res=2//Skip res-1 pixels per loop to lower the resolution

/*
Displacement map properties
*/
var extrusion:Number = 1;
var extrusiontarget:Number = .1;
var tolerance:Number = 1;
var smoothness = 10;

//Sinewave 
var lasti = 0;
var sinedirection = -1;
var sineamplitude:Number = 3;
var sinespeed = 0.5;
var sinedensity = 100;

/*
Breathing animation
*/
var inhale:Number = 2;
var exhale:Number = 2;
var beforeInhale:Number = 0;
var beforeExhale:Number = 0;

/*
Add sliders to control the above variables
*/
gui.addGroup("Pixels being drawn")
gui.addSlider("linecount", 5, 35);
gui.addSlider("canvaswidth",30,999);
gui.addSlider("res",1,10);

gui.addGroup("Displacement Map")
gui.addSlider("smoothness", 1, 100,{callback:setblur});
gui.addSlider("tolerance", 1, 255);
gui.addSlider("extrusiontarget", 0.1, 3);

gui.addGroup("Sinwave")
gui.addSlider("sinedirection",-1,1);
gui.addSlider("sineamplitude",0,30);
gui.addSlider("sinespeed",0,10);

gui.addGroup("Breathing")
gui.addSlider("beforeInhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("inhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("beforeExhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("exhale",0,5);




/**
Loop
**/
function myEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    /*
    Start a new iteration of line drawing, triggered when you click anywhere ons tage
    */
    initdraw();
}




/**
Clear the lines
Clear the bmp data
Redraw the bitmpa data
Redraw the lines
**/

function initdraw():void {
    /*
    Clear previous lines and displacement map data
    Lance drawing of 35 lines
    */
    for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        holder.removeChild(lines[i]);
        lines[i] = null;
    }
    bmd = null;
    bmd = new BitmapData(canvaswidth,400);
    bmd.draw(mc);
    lines = [];
    for (i=0; i<35; i++) {
//  for (i=0; i<c.coords.length; i++) {
        drawlines(i);
    }

}


/**
plot the cordinates of each point absed on sin data and bmp brihgtness
**/

function drawlines(linenumber):void {
    /*
    Start to draw a line
    */
    line =new Shape();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xdddddd);
    line.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    line.graphics.moveTo(-1,0);
    /*
    Increase length by 1 * times resolution and 
    Adjust y values based on displacement map and sinewave data
    */
    for (j=0; j<canvaswidth; j+=res) {
        if (c.coords[linenumber][j] ==1100) {
            line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        } else {
            line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFffff);
        }
        brightness = Math.ceil(getbrightness(getcolor(j,c.coords[linenumber][j]))/tolerance) ;
        sinus= Math.sin((j + (lasti * sinespeed)) / sinedensity) * sineamplitude;
        line.graphics.lineTo(j,c.coords[linenumber][j]-sinus-(brightness*extrusion));

    }
    /*
    Close the path that the line is drawing
    */

    lasti -=  sinedirection;
    line.graphics.lineTo(500,1100);
    line.graphics.lineTo(-1,1100);
    line.graphics.endFill();
    lines.push(line);
    holder.addChild(line);

}






/*
Smoothness of displacement map
*/
var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();

function setblur():void {
    trace("sb");
    blur.blurX = smoothness;
    blur.blurY = smoothness;
    blur.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
    mc.word.filters = [blur];
}


/*
Functions to retrieve brightness of displacement map
*/

function getcolor(xx,yy):uint {
    var pixelValue:uint = bmd.getPixel(xx,yy);
    return pixelValue;
}


function getbrightness(colour):Number {
    var R:Number = 0;
    var G:Number = 0;
    var B:Number = 0;
    R +=  colour >> 16 & 0xFF;
    G +=  colour >> 8 & 0xFF;
    B +=  colour & 0xFF;
    var br = Math.sqrt(R * R * .241 + G * G * .691 + B * B * .068);
    return br;
}

/*
Makes the displacment map stringer then weaker
*/

function grow():void {
    TweenLite.to(this,inhale,{extrusion:extrusiontarget,onComplete:shrink,delay:beforeInhale});
}

function shrink():void {
    TweenLite.to(this,exhale,{extrusion:0,onComplete:grow,delay:beforeExhale});
}

function mouseDownHandler(e){
    grow();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myEnterFrame);
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

//Draws lines
initdraw();
setblur()
```

Comment: You can start by moving the sine to a lookup table.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Computing_sines

Comment: There's definitely some things that can be done, I'm going to start working through some optimization things you can do without really modifying the general algorithm (generally with regard to reducing object creation and addition/removal and you can factor out some of the math being done inside of your loops).

Comment: Since you are drawing single pixels anyway, you might want to consider using a `BitmapData` or `ByteArray` to hold and draw the pixels - this will eliminate the need for vector drawing altogether, and since the pixels contain actual color information, you will also streamline the brightness calculation algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

So far just a minor improvement in performance with regard to RAM usage, but haven't come up with anything aside from adjusting the resolution to significantly reduce the processing in the loop but I'll keep looking at it.  Also updated the array to use a vector.

```
/*
Click anywhere on the stage to start anim
*/
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import com.greensock.*;
import flash.display.Shape;
import uk.co.soulwire.*;
import net.hires.debug.Stats;
import uk.co.soulwire.gui.SimpleGUI;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
/*
How many pixels do we draw in each loop?
*/
var canvaswidth:Number = 999;
var linecount:Number=35;
var res=4;//Skip res-1 pixels per loop to lower the resolution

/*
Performance analyser and variable sliders
*/
var stats:Stats=new Stats();
stats.x = 1200
stats.y = 0;
addChild(stats);

var gui:SimpleGUI = new SimpleGUI(this,"Parameters","h",1000,0);
gui.show();

/*
Stores the base coordinates
*/
var c:Coordinates=new Coordinates();

/*
Holds the lines
*/
var holder:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
addChild(holder)

/*
Generic variables
*/
var lines:Vector.<Shape> = Vector.<Shape>([]);
var bmd:BitmapData=new BitmapData(999,400);
var brightness = 0;
var sinus=0;

/**
*
Parameters used to control the animaitons and extrusions
*
**/

/*
Displacement map properties
*/
var extrusion:Number = 1;
var extrusiontarget:Number = .1;
var tolerance:Number = 1;
var smoothness = 10;

//Sinewave 
var lasti = 0;
var sinedirection = -1;
var sineamplitude:Number = 3;
var sinespeed = 0.5;
var sinedensity = 100;

/*
Breathing animation
*/
var inhale:Number = 2;
var exhale:Number = 2;
var beforeInhale:Number = 0;
var beforeExhale:Number = 0;

var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();
/*
Add sliders to control the above variables
*/
gui.addGroup("Pixels being drawn")
gui.addSlider("linecount", 5, 35);
gui.addSlider("canvaswidth",30,999);
gui.addSlider("res",1,10);

gui.addGroup("Displacement Map")
gui.addSlider("smoothness", 1, 100,{callback:setblur});
gui.addSlider("tolerance", 1, 255);
gui.addSlider("extrusiontarget", 0.1, 3);

gui.addGroup("Sinwave")
gui.addSlider("sinedirection",-1,1);
gui.addSlider("sineamplitude",0,30);
gui.addSlider("sinespeed",0,10);

gui.addGroup("Breathing")
gui.addSlider("beforeInhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("inhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("beforeExhale",0,5);
gui.addSlider("exhale",0,5);

/**
Clear the lines
Clear the bmp data
Redraw the bitmpa data
Redraw the lines
**/
function myEnterFrame(event:Event=null):void {
    /*
    Clear previous lines and displacement map data
    Lance drawing of 35 lines
    */
    bmd.draw(mc);
    for (var i:int=0; i<linecount; i++)
        drawlines(i);
}
function createLines()
{
    for (var i:int=0; i<linecount; i++)
    {
        var line:Shape = new Shape();
        lines.push(line);
        holder.addChild(line);
    }
}
/**
plot the cordinates of each point absed on sin data and bmp brihgtness
**/
function drawlines(linenumber):void
{
    /*
    Start to draw a line
    */
    var line:Shape = lines[linenumber];
    line.graphics.clear();
    line.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    line.graphics.moveTo(-1,0);
    /*
    Increase length by 1 * times resolution and 
    Adjust y values based on displacement map and sinewave data
    */
    for (var j:uint=0; j<canvaswidth; j+=res)
    {
        var currentNum:int = c.coords[linenumber][j];
        if (currentNum == 1100)
            line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        else
            line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFFFF);
        brightness = Math.ceil(getbrightness(bmd.getPixel(j,currentNum))/tolerance);
        sinus = Math.sin((j + (lasti * sinespeed)) / sinedensity) * sineamplitude;
        line.graphics.lineTo(j,currentNum-sinus-(brightness*extrusion));
    }

    /*
    Close the path that the line is drawing
    */
    lasti -=  sinedirection;
    line.graphics.lineTo(500,1100);
    line.graphics.lineTo(-1,1100);
    line.graphics.endFill();
}


var colourDict:Object = {};
function getbrightness(colour):Number
{
    if(colourDict[colour])
        return colourDict[colour];

    var R:Number = 0;
    var G:Number = 0;
    var B:Number = 0;
    R +=  colour >> 16 & 0xFF;
    G +=  colour >> 8 & 0xFF;
    B +=  colour & 0xFF;
    var br = Math.sqrt(R * R * .241 + G * G * .691 + B * B * .068);
    colourDict[colour] = br;
    return br;
}

/*
Makes the displacment map stringer then weaker
*/
function grow():void
{
    TweenLite.to(this,inhale,{extrusion:extrusiontarget,onComplete:shrink,delay:beforeInhale});
}

function shrink():void
{
    TweenLite.to(this,exhale,{extrusion:0,onComplete:grow,delay:beforeExhale});
}

function mouseDownHandler(e)
{
    grow();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myEnterFrame);
}

/*
Smoothness of displacement map
*/
function setblur():void
{
    trace("sb");
    blur.blurX = smoothness;
    blur.blurY = smoothness;
    blur.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
    mc.word.filters = [blur];
}

//Draws lines
createLines();
myEnterFrame();
setblur();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
```

Comment: Unless you are using a Vector of either `Number`, `int` or `uint`, the performance will actually drop compared to `Array`. "Under the hood", any derivate of `Vector.<Object>` is managed by the same data structure (there are no real generics!), and thus additional type checks are performed, which can slow down your application quite significantly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays/8551727#8551727

Comment: @weltraumpirat well alright I'll try modifying that later, too late here right now thanks for the pointer though

Comment: Hey thank you for that. I'll compare it to the existing as shaun suggest it may not be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

For one, you should be using drawPath, so you can reduce the amount of function calls that you need.  Since you're points are static, it'd be similar to the way you would build buffers on a gpu.

- Function calls are drawing commands are going to be the most expensive things here, so you should attempt to inline any utility function.
- Flatten the data in the bitmap, so it's a a faster array access call [] rather than getpixel(etc)

What is:

```
line.graphics.lineTo(500,1100);
line.graphics.lineTo(-1,1100);
```

????????????  This is quite a bit of work to do for the path plotter.  And why are you using fill if you're just showing lines?  Fill is not a small amount of cpu work.

Comment: Than you, I'll have to try it out. those two lines make the line forma path that can be filled wiht black, otherwise you would see lines through other lines.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that affects anything, because I'm not seeing them overlap.  Try then setting linethickness to 0, or setting quality to StageQuality.MEDIUM/LOW.  Another thing you can do if you're running into a long loop, is split the work into chunks -- ie -- half the lines in one frame, half the other lines in another.  If you're frameRate > 30, you shouldn't see too many visual artifacts with it.

Comment: I have updated the code to use drawPath. I wasn't sure what you meant about flattening the bitmap data, but have also changed the code so that bitmapdata is only reset when the smoothness slider is moved. Maybe I can store the brihgtness values in an array soa s not to have to read on each loop. Am trying to paste the code into this window, but don't know how, so will edit my initial message wiht new code.