# Is it sensible to use AS3 Vectors for class instances?

Tags: arrays, performance, actionscript-3, vector

Here is a simple code :

```
var a:Array = new Array( ins0, ins1, ins2, ins3,...., ins10000) ;
findIns( ins1500) ;

function findIns( ins:SomeInstance ) {  
    for ( var i = 0 ; i< a.length ; i++)  {
        if ( a[i] == ins ) {
            trace ( "FOUND IT");
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code there is NO  "int" or "string". They are instances of some complex class. So is it sensible to use Vectors in place of arrays in this case.

In my opinion it should be sensible, because instances are "numerical-memory-locations" afterall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the array are all instances of the same class, then yes `Vector` will definitely performs better than `Array`.

See the documentation for more information:

- Performance: array element access and iteration are much faster when using a Vector instance than they are when using an Array.
- Type safety: in strict mode the compiler can identify data type errors. Examples of data type errors include assigning a value of the incorrect data type to a Vector or expecting the wrong data type when reading a value from a Vector. Note, however, that when using the push() method or unshift() method to add values to a Vector, the arguments' data types are not checked at compile time. Instead, they are checked at run time.
- Reliability: runtime range checking (or fixed-length checking) increases reliability significantly over Arrays.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

Comment: This answer is actually wrong.  Vector **only** performs better when it's a number type vector. Vectors for any subtype of `Object` are actually slower than `Array`. See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays/8551727#8551727 for an explanation.

Comment: Nonetheless, what you said about reliability and type safety does apply - I'll gladly remove the down vote if you clarify the performance statement. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. What gets stored inside the vector is a reference to your object, not your object itself. You can check that doing the following:

```
var ref:yourType = a[0];
a[0] = someOtherObjectInstance;
trace(ref.toString());
```

You will find that `ref` still points to your original object.