# Initializing a Vector with an unknown class type

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I initialize a Vector with a class that is stored in a variable?

```
function initVector(Type:Class) {
    var vec:Vector.<Type> = new Vector.<Type>()
}
```

`initVector(int)` gives compiler errors:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Type.
1120: Access of undefined property Type.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've researched and explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551527/as3-vector-of-arrays), specifying a non-generic type for your vector will only make a difference, if you're using a number type (`int`, `uint` or `Number`) - those are the performance-optimized variations. All other vectors are really the same generic `Vector.<Object>` "under the hood" - all type checking is done at compile time, to give you some help with code completion etc., but has absolutely no effect at runtime.

Therefore, unless you will be using only numbers (in which case casting to Number might be an idea), it's absolutely OK to use a `Vector.<Object>`, or better yet: an Array.

Comment: So from what I understand, you're saying that the `Array` is preferable to the `Vector` in all cases except for containers of `int`, `uint`, and `Number`? So what is the point of using a `Vector` for types other than the aforementioned?

Comment: That would be oversimplifying things. In a lot of cases, using the typed vectors reduces the amount of code you have to write, and makes it more readable. Performance-wise they may not be the better choice, but I would choose readability over performance 90% of the time - only when the alternative would be `Vector.<Object>`, when there's noticeable need for performance optimization, or when you make extensive use of modifications you would serve better by using Array's broader APIs should you decide otherwise.

Comment: In your case, the type of the vector would be decided at runtime, so your code would have to be generic and use introspection, type casting, etc., anyway - in other words, there is nothing to be gained by using vectors.